# How can I store values entered in the standart input in a vector?

Tags: python

I have a question about vectors in Python.

So currently, I want to store all values entered on the standart input in a vector.

My biggest problem is that I don't have a predefined size for my Vector.

To be more explicit, this is my code and the output :

```
def main_loop():
    tab = np.array([])
    while (input() != "STOP"):
        tab = np.append(tab, float(input()))
    print(tab)

def main():
    main_loop()

main()
```

So the user will enter some values :

```
./Program
1
2
3
432
212
23
12
```

When I stop the loop, I want my vector containes : [1 2 3 432 212 23 12]

As you saw previously, I tried to use np append but this function add values at the end of my vector and delete the previous one.

How can I correct it and which function I need to use.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

In each loop iteration, you are getting input twice and throwing one of them away
This code works:

```
def main_loop():
    tab = np.array([])
    x = input()
    while (x != "STOP"):
        tab = np.append(tab, float(x))
        x = input()
    print(tab)

def main():
    main_loop()

main()
```